# Symfony Diem: how to secure whole frontend?

Tags: php, symfony, diem-cms

How can I secure whole frontend site, given that module responsible for login management (dmUser) is part of frontend, so it cannot be called without login (eternal forwards)? And if I write my custom login module it's still called via dmFront, i.e. within "secure zone" and ends up with eternal forwards?

One solution would be making each and every front page secure individually, but it's not possible due to specifics of this particular projet

Comment: What would be the problem with having an non-secure authentication module and the rest of the front end requiring an authenticated user?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about diem specifically, but typically you would edit `apps/frontend/config/security.yml` and set:

```
default:
  is_secure: true
```

And then set your actions that need to be insecure (login, forgot password etc) as `is_secure: false`. See the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/08-Security) but an example you could create `/apps/frontend/your_module_that_handles_logins/config/security.yml` and put:

```
Login:
  is_secure: false

Forgot_password:
  is_secure: false
```

And whatever other actions you need to not be secure.